# Firestore returning not all documents for a collection

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a flight planner for android. For the use of a certain REST API I need ICAO identifiers for each airport. I am trying to fetch about 14k documnets from firestore and map them to objects. 
Structure of my firestore:
[image: firebase structur]

In the result I got exacly 7698 documents in return every time.

```
    val db = Firebase.firestore
    val airports = db.collection("airport")
    val myColl : ArrayList<AirportDAO> = arrayListOf()
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var end : Long

    airports.get().addOnSuccessListener {
        end = System.currentTimeMillis()
        Log.d("firebase", (end - start).toString())
        val docs = it.documents
        Log.d("size", it.size().toString())     // <-- 7698
        for (doc in docs) {
            val a = doc.toObject(AirportDAO::class.java)
            if (a != null)
                myColl.add(a)
        }

        Log.d("size", myColl.size.toString())  // <-- 7698

    }
```

Method `get()` should return all DocumentSnapshots. Are there any limitations I am not aware of?

@Edit: End of my collection. "Filtruj" means "Sort" in Polish

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting differently? It sounds like your collection has exactly 7698 documents in it.

Comment: Are you always willing to get all items at once?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have exacly 14110 documents in my collection.

Comment: How are you counting those 14110 documents?  The code is suggesting you have 7698.  The API is not going to withhold any documents. If some limit is ever exceeded, you will see an error, not partial results.

Comment: @AlexMamo I wanted to fetch all data at once, because instances of this class are used frequently

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated the question.

Comment: Well, we can't see that every single number is used in your collection.  All you are showing is that you have a document called "14110", not that you have 14110 documents each with a distinct ID in numerical order.

Comment: I looked briefly at ID's and you're right. There are gaps between some IDs. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a listener on the following reference:

```
val airports = db.collection("airport")
```

It means that want to get all `AirportDAO` objects that exist within your `airport` collection. If the size of your `myColl` list is `7698`, it means that you'll be charged with **7698** read operation when you access that collection, which in my opinion is pretty much.

> I have exactly 14110 documents in my collection.

No, you don't! You have exactly 7698, that's what your code says.

If you want to filter the results, you should use `Query`. If you'll always need all of them, then you'll create a heavy traffic with Firestore.

Comment: Look at the second screen in the question, please.

Comment: Seeing that `14105` id, it doesn't really mean that you have 14105 documents. That's id isn't relevant, You probably have a document that is missing. The real number of documents is provided by `myColl.size.toString()`.

Comment: I looked briefly at ID's and you're right. There are gaps between some IDs. Thank you for your time.